# Create a folder in the path the user chose and name the folder like i want

Tags: excel, vba

I have no experience in VBA, but i'm trying to make a user select a path for a folder that need to be create if it doesn't exist and then extract three column of Excel that will go inside a text file inside the created folder.

with the help of you guys my code is working now!!

what kind of changes should i make it work? and if you know a way to simplify my code it would be great!

```
Sub register_formated_data()
'
' register_formated_data Macro
'
Dim order As Object
Dim Folder As Object
Dim Folder_path As String
Dim lastrow As Long

FolderName = "Formated Files"
Filename = "formated" & Right(File_path, InStr(File_path, "\"))

Dim FL As String ' FL is for file location

Sheets(8).Cells(12, 12).Value = ""

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)   '
    .Title = "Select the folder"                       'Open the file explorer
    .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"         'for you to select
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails            'the file you want
    .AllowMultiSelect = True                           'to format
    .Show                                              '

    On Error GoTo PROC_EXIT
    If Not .SelectedItems(1) = vbNullString Then FL = .SelectedItems(1)

End With

Sheets(8).Cells(12, 12).Value = FL

Folder_path = FL + "\" + FolderName

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fso.FolderExists(Folder_path & FolderName) Then
fso.CreateFolder(Folder_path).Name = FolderName

End If
```

PROC_EXIT:
End Sub

Comment: You may want to take a look at [`MkDir`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mkdir-statement) for creating a directory or folder.

Comment: @alexilas  How can the user select a path to a folder that doesn't exist ? The user can select a parent folder and check for a folder within it. For example the user select c:\temp\ and if the folder c:\tenp\Formated Files\ does not exist create it. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: @CDP1802 yest that's what i wanted to say. and from what i read on 'mkdir',  it seem to be something i should consider! ... i'm not sure how should i implement the mkdir but i'll search a bit

Comment: @Cyril I find a way to make my code work but i'm interest in `mkdir `methode!! is there any examples on stackoverflow??

Comment: @alexilas If you use a [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/filesystemobject-object) like in your post you can use the CreateTextFile method on the same object to create your dump file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fso.Name` is not a method or property of a FSO. All you need is the `CreateFolder` but make sure the path ends with the desired name of the folder. So it should read:

```vb
fso.CreateFolder FFolder_Path
```

Also pointing out here that you say `Folder_path` not `ffolder_path`. I would name your folder path something more meaningful to avoid this mistake in the future. Especially given that it starts with 2 repeat characters.

---

Just looked again at your code, not sure why you have a `For` loop that is from 1 to 1, unless you want it there for possible looping in the future (though if it looped, it would just continuously overwrite `FL` until the last item in the collection):

```vb
For lngCount = 1 To 1
            'MsgBox .SelectedItems(lngCount)
            On Error GoTo PROC_EXIT
            If .SelectedItems(lngCount) <> "" Then          'if the file exist, folder_location take the value of the selected file
                FL = .SelectedItems(lngCount)
            Else
                End
            End If
            'MsgBox "Text :" & previous_version_folder
        Next lngCount
```

I'd just say

```vb
On Error GoTo PROC_EXIT
If Not .SelectedItems(1) = vbNullString Then FL = .SelectedItems(1)
```

Comment: Add`Option Expicit`hint! What had prevented error on`so.CreateFolder Folder_path`and`folder.Name`could be used like`fso.CreateFolder(FFolder_path).Name = FolderName`

Comment: @jclasley I think you meant Option Explicit

Comment: @ComputerVersteher i'm not sure to understand why i should add `Option explicit`. since i'm a total "noob" having implicit var should help me ... right??

Comment: @alexilas. Ah, welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! What was the result of asking a search engine on "vba option explicit"? If you don't understand parts of the result, you may  ask, but always show own effort (and putting question into search engine is the minimum!).

Comment: @ComputerVersteher i search for the `option explicit` but i guess that my last comment wasn't explicit enough (no pun intend) on the microsoft page for `option explicit`, they say that if turned on, i must declare every var that i use! from what i understand is that if i try to implement some improvised var it will send me an error unless it's a good thing to have to declare every var used? oh and btw, thanks for the tour link!! i didn't though there was a specific way to ask question! i'll read that!!

Comment: @alexilas as [Option Explicit](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/13935/option-explicit) reveals most typos, it's mandatory!

Comment: @ComputerVersteher ok so it work like an "idiot-proof" (not trying to be insolent here!) even if it gives me more errors. it's there to be sure there's no typo... right? does it work the other way around?? like if i say `AS = DF and ER = DF` does it flag the fact that DF is use on multiple var?

Comment: @alexilas Nobody is typo-resistent! And vars should be dimed(limited) to a proper [data-type](https://riptutorial.com/vba/topic/3418/data-types-and-limits).  And no, it is valid to store a var to another one (e.g. interim result), as long it is used. For notifications on unused vars (and other code quality issues), you can use [RubberduckVBA](http://rubberduckvba.com/).